# setcookie() not working in internet explorer or safari

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies, safari, setcookie

I had the following code:

```
setcookie('username', $email, false, 'affiliates/', 'www.mydomain.com');
```

It wasn't working in IE or Safari. Then I changed it to:

```
setcookie('username', $email, time()+60*60*24, 'affiliates/', 'www.mydomain.com');
```

And it started working. Now, 2 days later, it doesn't work again. I don't think I changed anything. The setting of the cookie is being checked in another file, with this code:

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['username']) ) {
    ...
}
else {
    print( "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=index.html'>" );
    exit();
}
```

It always redirects to index.html (in Safari and IE). Any ideas why this would cease to work? (I've made sure cookies are enabled in both browsers).

One thing I did during the time it stopped working was test the site running on localhost. I changed the code to:

```
setcookie('username', $email, time()+60*60*24, 'affiliates/', null);
```

But only for the localhost version.

Comment: Setting the password in a cookie is a terrible idea, since this means it's transferred back and forth with every single request and greatly enhances the chance of it being intercepted. And it's viable to reverse an MD5 hash these days. While you may have a problem with cookies, you may want to go back and think about a better solution for the bigger problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: I guess you're right, just setting the username cookie is all I need.

Comment: And then users can change their username and be logged in as someone else.

Comment: They would still need the correct password. The only purpose of the cookie is to prevent someone from directly typing in the URL of someone else's homepage.

Comment: And what is the use of that? If they're not allowed to see a page, check on the server if they're authenticated and allowed to see the page and decline the request if not. Storing just the username in a cookie will probably not hinder any serious "attacker" in any way.

Comment: Pretty much every website uses cookies to validate logins.

Comment: Yes, but they use sessions and/or other *random opaque tokens* that can be expired server-side. Just the well-known user name is not a *secure secret*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have setcookie before all the other output? Headers can't be set after any like text or html. Maybe you need to remove any space above your

Also, the cookie must be set and used from the same domain and path.

Comment: "Also, the cookie must be set and used from the same domain and path." The cookie is set in mydomain.com/signin.php, and it's checked in mydomain.com/affiliates/homepage.php. That's why I set the path as "affiliates/". Is that correct?

Comment: Cookie will be rejected when the value for the Path attribute is not a prefix of the request-URI. Did it work without the path?

Comment: Yes. I changed "affiliates/" to "/" and now it seems to be working.